# Media object in Bootstrap with embedded ruby

Tags: css, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

I am trying to add an image in a bootstrap media object using embedded ruby. I tried a bunch of different things and nothing worked. This is what I have right now. Any idea of how to achieve this?

```
<div class="media">
   <a class="pull-left" href="">
      <img class="media-object" src="/assets/images/computer.jpg" alt="Commerical">
      <%= image_tag('computer.jpg') %>
   </a>
 <div class="media-body">
   <h4 class="media-heading">Commercial</h4>
            ...
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the [`image_tag` documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag) for Rails 4.1 you find

```
image_tag("/icons/icon.gif", class: "menu_icon")
# => <img alt="Icon" class="menu_icon" src="/icons/icon.gif" />
```

so you should be able to do just

```
<%= image_tag('computer.jpg', class: 'media-object', alt: 'Commerical') %>
```

and be done with it. But it would really help if you posted the HTML you get and discuss why it does not satisfy the result you desire.

Comment: You should be more specific about what you would consider to be "working". Please add the HTML you expect if you can or at least the one you get. If the rendering does not conform to your likings you should probably post a picture.

Comment: I just tried it again and it worked! Not sure what happened but I'll take it! I probably missed something the first time I tried it. Thanks!